# Load WebformSubmission back for editing

Tags: drupal, webforms, drupal-9

I have the following setup: A webform embedded into a custom page. When the user submits the webform, they get redirected to a different website (stripe checkout page). On that page, they have an option to go back which will lead them back to the original page with the webform but with the submission's ID as a GET param. How can I load the given submission back to the form for the user to edit?

What I've tried so far is:

1. I've tried to find a way to tell the webform to reuse an existing submission with little luck
2. I've tried to load the submission in the form alter, get its data and set it as default values to the current submission. To prevent building up a stock of unused submissions and avoid setting the default values over and over again (because I have. a multi page webform which will call form alter for every page), my plan was to delete the original submission after loading the default values. This didn't work either, I could not get the values to be loaded properly.